# no background in second screen (separate X screen)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, compiz, gnome, gnome-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When starting or log off/on, add'l panels show and some panel applets are duplicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138393/when-starting-or-log-off-on-addl-panels-show-and-some-panel-applets-are-duplic)

After upgrading to 12.04 Gnome Classic amd64, the second screen is pure white.  When launching the wallpaper shows up for a second then goes away.  Also, the panels are empty.

Comment: I am having the same issue. No idea where to go from here. I already played with nvidia-settings over and over. Display settings window does not show my second monitor; only my first one is displayed.

Comment: @Alex Ford I am working through this, but so far it looks like a problem related to nvidia-current/jockey.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/138393/when-starting-or-log-off-on-addl-panels-show-and-some-panel-applets-are-duplic/139520#139520

Comment: The post you linked talks about upgrading being an issue. I have installed 12.04 fresh on a new machine. Also, I didn't notice before but you mention Gnome Classic and I am using the default Unity interface. I get the same symptoms as you though.

Comment: I have carefully re-upgraded to 12.04, and I have the same problems.  I have filed a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1002641

Comment: @Alex Ford If you are getting the same symptoms, it would be helpful if you went to the launchpad bug report and mark it as affecting you.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1002641

Comment: Done and done..