# When starting or log off/on, add'l panels show and some panel applets are duplicated

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, compiz, gnome, gnome-panel

After upgrading to 12.04 Gnome Classic amd64,every time I log on a new additional blank panel appears on the top and bottom panels - which I delete every time.  In addition, the default panel applets are duplicated in the original panels.

Also the panels in the second screen are empty (in addition to the wallpaper being hidden).

Update:

As suggested by fossfreedomm I created a new user and the same behavior occurred.

I increased the height of the panels (24>36) and the added panels did not change.

If I don't remove the added panels and log off/on I get still another - they accumulate.

If I switch user instead of logoff/logon, the add'l panel do not appear.

Comment: does this occur if you create a new account and login with that?  The reason for the question - just wondering if this is a bug or a corruption in your users gnome/compiz config that needs resetting.

Comment: As an alternative to creating a new account, you could try this out with the guest account.

Comment: Well it is kind of reassuring that other people see this problem.  Not great that there does not seem to be a solution for it though.  Could I switch drivers away from nvidia and expect to see things improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparently results from a 10.10 repository error where nvidia-current update was botched and as a work-around I installed driver from nvidia.  This resulted in a botched 10.10>11.04, then a botched 11.04>11.10, then a botched 11.10>12.04 release upgrade. It kind of incredible that the resulting 12.04 would boot at all. 
Remarkably, the same thing on a 32bit system worked perfectly.
The solution apparently will be to fix the 11.04 so the following upgrades will work, if that is possible.
Fortunately I have backed up each step.

**UPDATE:**
Mismatch seen after upgrading without nvidia-propietary: [image]

**UPDATE** This now seems to be associated with 12.04's inability to support a second monitor (at least in amd64 with nvidia graphic adapters).  These occur when adding/deleting 2nd monitor (screen1) using nvidia settings and logging on/off.  Bug reports have been filed, [Bug #1002641](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1002641) and [Bug #1001712](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1001712) and possibily related to [Bug #1002602](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1002602) and [Bug #729979](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/729979)

This also occurs with Unity.

**UPDATE** [Bug #1002641](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1002641) is getting a little attention but nobody is assigned to work on it.  After today's update, I now have the Unity Dash Totem on my Gnome fallback/classic screen obscuring the Gnome top panel and pretty much making 12.04 useless.  Thank goodness I have a working 10.04 also running so I can get some work done.

Comment: Upgrade 10.10>11.04 fails due to nvidia-current, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1002385